# Is Mechon Mamre Considered a Source?

Tags: discussion, citing-sources

Earlier today I quoted an article published by Mechon Mamre with no written author. The article is: https://mechon-mamre.org/jewfaq/animals.htm

The quote I used from them as a source was "Under Jewish law, animals have some of the same **rights** as humans do.  Animals rest on Shabbat, as humans do.  We are forbidden to muzzle an ox while it is working in the field, just as we must allow human workers to eat from the produce they are harvesting."

It's established that quoting Scripture from Mechon Mamre is a source, but is an unnamed writer from the website a valid Jewish source?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a valid Jewish source". Valid for what purpose?

Comment: Valid as a source for an answer considering the author of the article is unknown. It may be a Jewish website, and it's a well known source for text of books. But is an unauthored article on the website also a valid source?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Valid for what purpose? What standard are you trying to meet?

Answer (score 2):

With respect to expected behavior on Mi Yodeya, anonymous articles at Mechon Mamre should be [properly cited](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75/how-should-i-cite-an-answer-elsewhere), so that readers are aware of the source and enabled to make their own judgement about its value, just like any other source.